# How is SECURITY_MODE_COMMAND message requests to start/stop ciphering?

Tags: security, networking, encryption, 3g

I read about SECURITY_MODE_COMMAND that it's sent by the NW to stop/start enciphering of messages.
I could not find in SECURITY_MODE_COMMAND message structure what fields I need to check in order to find out if ciphering should begin or should end.
Can I get some help with that ?

Comment: 3g cellular networking

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with the topic, but it seems to be for LTE/4G and not 3G.

Comment: it's also for UMTS, which is 3g.

Comment: I guess we can allow protocol related questions. I've upvoted, but I sincerely hope we've got some 3G experts on this Q/A site. Otherwise you may have to resort to some forums that specialize in telecom.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about the NAS Security_Mode_Command message, described in [TS 33.401](http://www.3gpp.org/DynaReport/33401.htm) section 7.2.4.4, and defined in [TS 24.301](http://www.3gpp.org/DynaReport/24301.htm) section 8.2.20.

From TS 24.301 section 8.2.20, we can see that Security_Mode_Command contains the information element "Selected NAS Security Algorithms", which is defined in section 9.9.3.23.

I think the answer to your question is, that you should check this field.
If it contains a valid value for an algorithm, then ciphering should be switched on using this algorithm.   But if ciphering is already on, and it contains

> 0 0   0       EPS encryption algorithm EEA0 (null ciphering algorithm)

then no ciphering should be applied.  Therefore, you could interpret that as "switch off ciphering".

But I also note that the same spec says in section 8.2.20 Security Mode Command, that

> This message is sent by the network to the UE to establish NAS signalling security.

So, I'm not completely sure if it should be sent to switch ciphering off, as that's not specifically mentioned in the spec.